# jquery-inputmask event trigger on not complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, input-mask, jquery-inputmask

we are using [jquery-inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask) on some our textbox-inputs:

```
<input data-inputmask="'alias': 'dd/mm/yyyy'"/>
```

does this js library includes some validation that force the user to fill the input completely, before he/she jumps to another input?
For example:
an alert will be triggered when the user only fill 23/10/2yyy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this can be achieved by using this on initialization:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#date").inputmask("d/m/y",{ "onincomplete": function(){ alert('inputmask incomplete'); } });
});
```

however what i used is actually simpler, which, just clear everything.

```
<input data-inputmask="'alias': 'dd/mm/yyyy', 'clearIncomplete': true"/>
```